# Probability of the 2,3,4 and 5 of Clubs dealt one each into 4 hands of 13 cards

Tags: probability

Simple card game “Spades”, 13 cards to 4 players. Big score is from a bid and made zero tricks. Play begins with each player required to play lowest Club in hand. What is the probability of the 5 of Clubs taking that first trick (and the zero bid being defeated)?

Answer (score 2):

So, your question is what is the probability that each of the $2\clubsuit, 3\clubsuit, 4\clubsuit, 5\clubsuit$ each were distributed to different people?

Well, someone gets the $2$.  What is the probability that the $3$ went to someone else?  This will be $\frac{39}{51}$ as there are $51$ remaining equally likely positions in players hands that the $3$ could occupy, $39$ of which are in a hand different than the hand holding the $2$.

Given that the two and the three are in different players' hands what is the probability that the $4$ went to someone else?  This will be $\frac{26}{50}$

Finally, given that the two three and four all went to different players' hands, the probability that the $5$ went to the final remaining hand will be $\frac{13}{49}$

The overall probability that each of these cards went to different players is then the product of these:

$$\frac{39\cdot 26\cdot 13}{51\cdot 50\cdot 49}$$